# infinitive/comma/sentence fragment question

Tags: commas, conjunctions

> Cabs can drive people anywhere, but cannot be hailed at, or below Jon Street and Frank Street.

My question is should there be a comma after *anywhere*?
Is *but* a conjunction in this case? I am not sure, because "[cabs] cannot be hailed at, or below Jon Street and Frank Street," is giving me trouble.
Is *be hailed* a infinitive in which case the phrase two lines up is not a sentence because there is no verb?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We appreciate added information about your question, such as the context of your question, what you have found (or what confused you) when you researched the answer, etc. With more information, you're more likely to get a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

*But* is a conjunction (as it usually is).

*Be* is an infinitive.

*cannot* is the finite (modal) verb of that branch of the coordination, parallel with *can* in the other branch.

I would use a comma before *but*, and I would also use one after *below*, otherwise the grouping of the coordinations is unclear.